# Bizarre/Random Segfault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

EDIT: Clarifying.

- fout is is a FILE*.  (I thought this was irrelevant since that line clearly compiles)
- there is A LOT of code above these last few lines; I guess I could dump them all but I imagine you're not overly interested in debugging my stuff.  I'm more interested, generally, in what could possibly occur that would segfault at return 0 but not before.

Warning: My C is terrible.

I've got a C program which, from the likes of it, just *wants* to segfault.  I'll spare you the other, irrelevant details, but here's the big picture:

### My code:

```
//...other code
printf("finished \n");   
fclose(fout);   
printf("after fclose \n");  
return 0;
```

### The output:

> finished
>   after fclose
>   Segmentation fault

I'm compiling with GCC, -std=c99.

### My question:

How the heck is this even possible?  What should I be looking at, that may be causing this (seemingly random) segfault?  Any ideas?

Much thanks!

Comment: Those "details" are not "irrelevant".

Comment: What's `fout` ? Has anyone assigned `stdout` to it?

Comment: Just so you know, if you end a line with two spaces, it will add a forced line break before the next line, and if you indent a block of text with four spaces it will preformat it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whatever the `return` is going back to is causing the fault.  If this code snippet is in  `main()`, then the code has inflicted damage to the stack, most likely by exceeding the bounds of a variable.  For example

```
int main ()
{
    int a [3];
    int j;

    for (j = 0;  j < 10;  ++j)
         a [j] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

This sort of thing could cause any of a number of inexplicable symptoms, including a segfault.

Comment: Thank you!  This is basically what I was trying to get at.  OK, great.

Comment: Using GDB will allow you to locate segfaults instantly, and also allow you to peruse the stack to locate any potentially wonky values.

Comment: I'm reading a number of GDB tutorials now.  But if my program only seg-faults at the very end, what should I be looking for above? Any recommended techniques?

Comment: Well start with seeing what operation caused the segfault in GDB. Without that, you can't go much further.

Just do gdb your-app
When started, type `run`, then `backtrace` after the segfault to examine the stack. You don't need to know any more about gdb than that.

Comment: If the cause is indeed trashing the stack, GDB will show a confused looking stack.  It probably won't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's probably a stack corruption related problem, you could also use a memory debugger to locate the source of the corruption, like [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/).
Just compile using `gcc -g` and then run `valgrind yourprog args`.

Comment: Thank you!  I later found this myself.  valgrind is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Does "Hello world!" program seg fault?  If so then you have a hardware problem.  If not then you have at least one problem in the code you're not showing us!

Answer (score 0):

Compile your program with the debug flag `gcc -g` and run your code in `gdb`.  You can't always trust the console to output "Segmentation fault" exactly when problematic code is executed or relative to other output.  In many cases this will be misleading -- you will find debugging tools such as `gdb` extremely useful.